Graphene field return null in answer even if exception was raised
I'm using Django + GraphQL to build a backend for my project. I have a User model defined in my models.py which have many fields including for instance email and telephone defined in the following piece of code:
email = models.EmailField(_("email address"), max_length=320, unique=True)
telephone = models.CharField(max_length=20, null=True, default=None, blank=True)

The definition for UserType is:
import graphene
from graphene_django import DjangoObjectType

from main.graphql import validators
from main.models import User


class UserType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            "id",
            "first_name",
            "last_name",
            "email",
            "birthdate",
            "birthplace",
        )
    def resolve_telephone(self, info):
        validators.verify_request_from_staff_user_or_from_superuser_if_target_staff(
            info, self, info.context.user, "telephone"
        )
        return self.telephone
    def resolve_verified_email(self, info):
        validators.verify_request_from_staff_user_or_from_superuser_if_target_staff(
            info, self, info.context.user, "verified_email"
        )
        return self.verified_email

verify_request_from_staff_user_or_from_superuser_if_target_staff is a simple function that raises an exception of type graphql.GraphQLError if request user is trying to access information that he cannot (i.e. Staff-user accessing other staff users of base-user accessing other users).
I have defined a query testUser which takes id as argument and return the user with such id. If i request the email field in the query the result data does not contain the email field (and this is my desidered behaviour), but if I request the telephone field the result data contains the field telephone with null value.
I know that this is due to null=True in telephone field definition, but I desire to not edit the db field.
How I can achieve the desired behaviour (which is the absence of such field in the response) for telephone field?
Examples:
query testEmail {
  testUser(id: 9) {
    email
  }
}
query testTelephone {
  testUser(id: 9) {
    telephone
  }
}

testEmail returns
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot access field 'email'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 3,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "testUser",
        "email"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "testUser": null
  }
}

testTelephone returns
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot access field 'telephone'",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 8,
          "column": 5
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "testUser",
        "telephone"
      ]
    }
  ],
  "data": {
    "testUser": {
      "telephone": null
    }
  }
}

Is it correct the way I'm limiting field access or is there a better/faster way to do so than writing resolvers for each field I want to limit access to?
